# What's the BruteForceMatcher_GPU in OpenCV 3.x

Tags: opencv, gpu, opencv3.1

I'm converting the source code and upgrading the library from OpenCV 2.x to OpenCV 3.x. Then I wonder how I have to change `BruteForceMatcher_GPU` in OpenCV 2.x to some module in OpenCV 3.x.

Just use `BFMatcher` without GPU support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenCV Transition guide](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html), you can read that:

> CUDA API has been updated (gpu module -> several cuda modules,
>   namespace gpu -> namespace cuda)

**Edit:**

On the documentation [page](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/dc5/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html) of the class `cuda::DescriptorMatcher`, it seems you can use `createBFMatcher()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry. No module in BFMatcher_CUDA in latest OpenCV. See the document below. http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/d1a/namespacecv_1_1cuda.html